# NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary how to filter using regex

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am new to ios.

I have a NSMutableArray of  **NSDictionary**. **How can I filter the array**?

```
//sections is a NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary elements

 [sections addObject:getName];
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorFirst = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"first" ascending:YES];
       NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorLast = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"last" ascending:YES];

       NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptorFirst,sortDescriptorLast,nil];

        NSArray *sortedArray =[sections sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptor];
```

How to continue the code from here in order to match the array with the regex value?

Comment: is there a reason you have to use regex? can you use NSPredicate instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need a string that contains all 
values of a dictionary. That would be:

```
NSString *str = [[dict allValues] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

and then you can check if `str` matches the given regex pattern as before.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Could you explain a little bit what does that line do? What is with allValues and why that componentsJoinedByString?

Comment: @justME: `allValues` returns an *array* of all the dictionary values, and `componentsJoinedByString` returns a *string* with all array elements, joined by the given separator. See the NSDictionary and NSArray documentation for more information.

Comment: why did you joined the elements with @" "? This line is the same with creating a NSMutableString and concatenating all the   NSString *Name=[dict valueForKey:@"first"]; (@"last")?

Comment: @justME: I have chosen a space as separator so that { first=John, last =Doe } becomes "John Doe" and not "JohnDoe". But you can choose an empty string as separator if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok from the look of your post it looks like you can just use an `NSPredicate` instead of a RegEx

try something along the lines of this:

```
NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key = %@", value];
NSArray* matches = [arrayOfDicts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

`NSPredicate` can use all sorts of operators such as `LIKE`, `!=`, and `<`

if you need to filter based on a value being in a list you can construct a predicate along the lines of `@"key IN %@", arrayOfPossibleValues`

replace `key` in that sample code with the key in the dictionary you are trying to filter by. you can filter using multiple keys if needed.

Comment: I need to use regex because my input values can be: [a-c0][m-p5]. This means I need to filter everything that contains a,b,c,m,n,p or 0 or 5 in the NSDictinary for all the keys

Comment: I am very sorry I didn t specify this. I did add this [sections enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary * dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop) {
            
             NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"first"];
            NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
            if (match)  {...} Could you tell me how to set in NSString *str the objects for the key=@"last"?

Comment: I still don't see why you cant use an NSPredicate. just use `@"key IN %@", arrayOfValues`

Comment: because I am creating a NSString in another method - based on some input keys. I already tested the code with a simple NSMutableSArray that has NSString objects and it works great. Please help me with the code I ve written

Comment: Is there a way I can have in NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"first"]+ [dict valueForKey:@"last"]; How to work this our? please help:)